# Why is this simple AngularJS ng-show not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I cannot figure out why my simple AngularJS app not working as intended. "Loading..." is supposed to be hidden, and "Done!" should be shown after 1 second.

html:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div class="text-center" ng-show="loading">
            <h1>Loading...</h1>

    </div>
        <div class="text-center" ng-show="!loading">
            <h1>Done!</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This post was helpful but the title doesn't lend itself to being googlable.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to tell angular that you updated the var:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

or just

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Allright thanks, just getting started with AngularJS, didn't know about apply. Thanks for the help. I chose this answer - because in my real app (not the jsfiddle), I got an error with StarsSky's approach of using $scope.apply().

Comment: You're getting the error with StarSky's answer, because the $timeout starts a digest cycle and $apply is trying to start a second one, but you can't have more then 1 digest going on at time.

Comment: This is the right thing to do, but why?  If I'm updating $scope with the new value, isn't that $scope property already on the $watch list, and should update the DOM automatically via the magic of two-way binding?  Not understanding why $scope.$apply() is necessary.

Comment: @darktideac .apply() isn't a function, it's $apply().

Comment: Use $q.defer(); the object returned allows you to call a .resolve() or .reject()  method once your async method is completed. Both resolve and reject methods of the $q.defer() object call $digest internally after the async method is resolved. The $digest tells angular to re-evaluate your $scope properties, which will do what you're looking for. It's a better practice. Avoid calling $apply() if you don't need to and if there are better, built-in angular mechanisms in place to take care of this.

Comment: @dennis.sheppard Did you get the answer of your question here ? I also have the same query.

Answer (score 14):

A nicer way of doing this is by calling `$scope.$digest();` to update your UI

Comment: I don't like this "trick", but worked for me (my `$scope` var is updated into a library callback). Thanks!

Comment: @user2553863: I didn't like it because the framework _shouldn't_ need the developer notifies it _when_ to update the UI, but AngularJS does sometimes. Angular 2+ don't have this issue anymore.

Comment: @dbautistav, you're right, is annoying and adds complexity. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `$timeout` and inject it in your controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2kjJ/)

Edit:
removed             `$scope.apply();` as @Salman suggested

Comment: if u already using $timeout then there is no need to use  $scope.apply(); because angular make sure value get updated using apply.

Comment: $apply(), not .apply()

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [**`apply()`**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) function to *stop loading* message.

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8fVH/15/)**.

JavaScript:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Hope this would be help you!

Answer (score 3):

when fire angular event to another object like setTimeout you should use

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.loading = false;
});
```

for example

```
var loading={
     show:function(){
        $scope.loading=true
     },
     hide:function(){
        $scope.loading=false
     }
}
```

may not working best way

```
   var loading={
         show:function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
               $scope.loading=true
            });
         },
         hide:function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
               $scope.loading=false
            });
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that one way to work around ng-show not evaluating in the way you want it to be is to use ng-class instead.

```
 <div class="mycontent" data-ng-class="{'loaded': !loading}">
```

This way when $scope.loading is not equal to true the css class 'loaded' will be added to the element.
Then you just need a to use the css class to show/hide the content.

```
.mycontent {
    display: none;
}

.loaded {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest problem here is that you are using a primitive as your model. The angular team recommends to use an object to tie your model to. For example:

```
scope.model = {};
scope.model.loading = false;
```

Then in your html:

```
<div class="text-center" ng-show="model.loading">
```

That way angular gets a reference to a field inside an object instead of a primitive being pointed to by a variable.